# Calculation island error with perlin noise

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, perlin-noise

I'm developing a small project, which is a grid of 100 x 100 hexagons.
In the script below, I paint my hexagons with the perlin noise, but the format I want to island does not go away.
I'll leave my code and 2 examples as my map stays and how I wish it to stay.

My island

[My Island](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uob5I.png)

As i need

[Im Need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZOFqd.png)

```
int getColor(float x, float z)
{
    xTO = (int)x / terrainWidth - 30;
    zTO = (int)z / terrainHeight - 30;

    float v = Mathf.PerlinNoise((xTO + x + seed) * freq, (zTO + z) * freq);
    //  v += 0.001f;

    float form = formWorld(x, z);


    if (v < 0.25f)
    {
        //water
        return 0;
    }
    else if (v < 0.5f)
    {
        //sand
        return 1;
    }

    else if (v < 0.75f)
    {
        //grass
        return 2;
    }
    else
    {
        //Trees / Forest
        MakeNewTree(new Vector3(xx, 0, z * 7.5f));
        return 2;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want your image to look more like the second one, the best option is going to be adding a circular gradient which offsets your Perlin Noise.

The easiest way to do this is to measure the distance from the center and combine that with the perlin noise.

Here's some *untested* code.

```
    int getColor(float x, float z)
    {
        xTO = (int)x / terrainWidth - 30;
        zTO = (int)z / terrainHeight - 30;

        float v = Mathf.PerlinNoise((xTO + x + seed) * freq, (zTO + z) * freq);
        //  v += 0.001f;
        v -= CircleOffset(x,z)/2; //Change the two to make the island bigger.

        float form = formWorld(x, z);


        if (v < 0.25f)
        {
            //water
            return 0;
        }
        else if (v < 0.5f)
        {
            //sand
            return 1;
        }

        else if (v < 0.75f)
        {
            //grass
            return 2;
        }
        else
        {
            //Trees / Forest
            MakeNewTree(new Vector3(xx, 0, z * 7.5f));
            return 2;
        }
    }

    float CircleOffset(float x, float y)
    {
        Vector2 center = new Vector2(terrainWidth/2,terrainHeight/2);
        float distance = Mathf.Sqrt((center.x - x)*(center.x - x) + (center.y - y) * (center.y - y));
        return distance/terrainWidth;
    }
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Unfortunately the result was not as expected, I left a link showing what happened.

https://imgur.com/a/D5kzrnZ